# ¿La función dispose() cierra por completo la instancia?

Tags: java, jframe

Tengo un `JFrame` que al presionar un botón se cierra mediante un `dispose()`, pero durante la ejecución si el usuario lo desea puede volverlo a abrir y se mostrará una información diferente.

El problema es que la primera vez que se abre funciona perfecto, pero cuando se abre por segunda vez empieza a fallar. Los labels, se ven dos veces y los eventos dejan de funcionar como deberían, y si se abre por tercera vez, los labels, salen tres veces. Es como si el `dispose()` no eliminase la instancia sino que la ocultase, y necesito que se cierre por completo esa instancia y solo vuelva a aparecer si se crea otra instancia pero que sea una nueva, no la anterior.

Aquí el frame con el que tengo problemas:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.lhumanizado.glenis.classes.TempData;

public class Gastos extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    public static ArrayList<TempData> db = new ArrayList();
    //Fuente
    public static boolean source = false;
    //Contador
    int count = 0;
    //Espacio del panel de Comision
    public static Component espace = Box.createVerticalStrut(12);
    //Elementos
    public static JTextField operacion = new JTextField(20);
    public static JTextField monto = new JTextField(20);
    public static JButton aceptar = new JButton("Aceptar");
    public static JButton finalizar = new JButton("Finalizar");
    //Paneles del Centro
    public static JPanel panelDescripcion = new JPanel();
    public static JPanel panelMonto = new JPanel();
    //Paneles de abajo
    public static JPanel abajoNorth = new JPanel();
    public static JPanel abajoSouth = new JPanel();
    public static JPanel abajoCenter = new JPanel();
    //Paneles Principales
    public static JPanel principal = new JPanel();
    public static JPanel arriba = new JPanel();
    public static JPanel abajo = new JPanel();

    //Labels de los Montos Finales
    JLabel labelTotal = new JLabel("Total");
    JLabel montoTotal = new JLabel("0.0" );

    Gastos(){
        super("Crea un nuevo estado de cuenta");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(950,500);
        setLayouts();
        addElements();
        JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(principal);
        add(scroller);
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        getRootPane().setDefaultButton(aceptar);
    }

    public void setLayouts(){
        principal.setLayout(new BoxLayout(principal, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        abajo.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        abajoNorth.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        abajoCenter.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        abajoSouth.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.TRAILING));
        panelDescripcion.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelDescripcion, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        panelMonto.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelMonto, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    }

    public void addElements(){
        //Elementos del Panel de Arriba
        arriba.add(new JLabel("Mes:"));
        arriba.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(15));
        arriba.add(new JLabel("Tipo de Operacion:"));
        arriba.add(operacion);
        arriba.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(15));
        arriba.add(new JLabel("Monto:"));
        arriba.add(monto);
        arriba.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(15));
        aceptar.addActionListener(this); //Listener del boton
        finalizar.addActionListener(this); //Listener del boton para guardar
        arriba.add(aceptar);
        arriba.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(40)); 
        //Boton de abajo
        abajoSouth.add(finalizar);
        //Paneles del centro
        prepararCentro();
        abajoCenter.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(15));
        abajoCenter.add(panelDescripcion);
        abajoCenter.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(300));
        abajoCenter.add(panelMonto);
        valorFinalShow();
        //Elementos del Panel de Abajo
        abajo.add(abajoNorth, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        abajo.add(abajoCenter, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        abajo.add(abajoSouth, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        principal.add(arriba);
        principal.add(new JSeparator(JSeparator.HORIZONTAL));//Linea del medio
        principal.add(abajo);
    }

    public static void prepararCentro(){
        panelDescripcion.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(15)); //Espacio
        panelMonto.add(new JLabel("Monto"));
        panelMonto.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(15)); //Espacio
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource().equals(aceptar)){
            try{
                if(!operacion.getText().equals("")){
                    db.add(new TempData(operacion.getText(), Double.parseDouble(monto.getText())));
                    valorFinal();
                    add(count);
                    valorFinalShow();
                    monto.setText(null);
                    operacion.setText(null);
                    count++;
                    validate();
                    repaint();
                }else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ingrese una operacion valida!");
                    monto.setText(null);
                    operacion.setText(null);
                }    
            }catch(NumberFormatException ex){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Inserte un valor valido!");
                monto.setText(null);
                operacion.setText(null);
            }
        }else{
            new Bienvenida();dispose();System.gc();
        }
    }

    public void add(int count){
        panelDescripcion.add(new JLabel(db.get(count).operacion));
        panelDescripcion.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
        panelMonto.add(new JLabel(String.valueOf(db.get(count).monto)));
        panelMonto.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
    }

    public void valorFinalShow(){
        //Añade los labels
        panelDescripcion.add(labelTotal);
        //Añade los montos             
        panelMonto.add(montoTotal);
    }

    public void valorFinal(){
        double tmp = 0;
        for(int i = 0; db.size() > i; i++){
            tmp += db.get(i).monto;
        }
        montoTotal.setText(String.valueOf(tmp));
    }

    public void renew(){
        panelDescripcion.removeAll();
        panelMonto.removeAll();
        prepararCentro();
        valorFinal();
        for(int i = 0; i< db.size();i++){
                add(i);
        }
        count = db.size();
        valorFinalShow();
        validate();
        repaint();
    }

}

class TempData {
    public String operacion = "";
    public double monto = 0;

    public TempData(String operacion, double monto){
        this.operacion = operacion;
        this.monto = monto;
    }
}
```

Y este es el Frame que lo invoca

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Bienvenida extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    //Creacion de Botones
    JButton editar = new JButton(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Josue/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Glenis/src/com/lhumanizado/glenis/img/edit.png"));
    JButton nuevo = new JButton(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Josue/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Glenis/src/com/lhumanizado/glenis/img/save.png"));
    JPanel derecha = new JPanel(); //Panel de Nuevo
    Bienvenida(){
        //Operaciones del Frame
        super("Bienvenido, admin!");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(350,245);
        //Añade los listeners
        nuevo.addActionListener(this);
        editar.addActionListener(this);
        //Creacion de los Labels
        JLabel labelEditar = new JLabel("Editar");
        JLabel labelNuevo = new JLabel("Nuevo");
        //Creacion de los Paneles
        JPanel principal = new JPanel(); //Panel principal
        JPanel centro = new JPanel();
        JPanel izquierda = new JPanel(); //Panel de Editar

        //Asignacion de Layouts
        izquierda.setLayout(new BoxLayout(izquierda, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        derecha.setLayout(new BoxLayout(derecha, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        principal.setLayout(new BoxLayout(principal, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        //ToolTipText
        nuevo.setToolTipText("Crea un nuevo estado de cuenta");
        editar.setToolTipText("Edita un estado de cuenta existente");
        //Añadir objetos al panel de la izquierda
        izquierda.add(editar);
        izquierda.add(labelEditar);
        //Alinea ambos en el centro de cada uno
        editar.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        labelEditar.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        //Añadir objetos al panel de la derecha
        derecha.add(nuevo);
        derecha.add(labelNuevo);
        //Alinea Ambos en el centro de cada uno
        nuevo.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        labelNuevo.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

        principal.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(20));//Espacio en blanco de arriba
        //Añadir los objetos del centro
        centro.add(izquierda);
        centro.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(20));//Espacio en blanco entre editar y nuevo
        centro.add(derecha);

        principal.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(20));//Espacio en blanco de abajo
        //Añadir a principal
        principal.add(centro);

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        add(principal);
        setVisible(true);


    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
        if(evt.getSource() == nuevo){
            new Gastos();
        }
        dispose();
    }
    public static void main(String [] args){
        new Bienvenida();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Awes0meM4n En ese post atribuyen el fallo a usar this, lo cual no hago y en mi caso la ventana si se cierra, el problema es que al volver a crear una instancia se muestra la anterior en vez de crearse una nueva, también había leído la parte de que si la ventana se cierra y se vuelve a llamar se mostraría el mismo contenido pero probé haciendo dos JFrame simples con un label y un botón y el error no se producía, si dispose no es la función que tengo que utilizar para conseguir lo que quiero, cual debo usar entonces?

Comment: Aunque en aquel caso fuera fallo del `this` explica que podía deberse a otro motivo. En él explica que no cierra por completo la instancia y se puede volver a abrir. Como preguntas eso, eso es lo que responde a tu pregunta. En tu caso el fallo es el segundo caso. Como no se cierra pero vuelves a crear y agregar nuevos botones, es por eso que se te repiten. Si sigues sin ver cuál es tu fallo después de este comentario lo pondré en una respuesta, pero es un fallo muy simple del tipo "anda no me he dado cuenta". Si terminas cerrando la pregunta entenderé que lo has visto.

Comment: @Awes0meM4n vale, entiendo ahora que el segundo caso es el que responde mi pregunta, y si sabía que se veían dos veces los labels debido a eso, pero pensaba que estaba cometiendo un error en la llamada al dispose o algo por el estilo, sin embargo sigo sin pillarlo, si pudieras ayudarme te lo agradecería

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que en la clase `Gastos` tienes muchos elementos declarados estáticamente. Esto quiere decir que **la primera vez que se usa la clase** `Gastos` creas los objetos que luego rellenas cada vez que creas un **objeto del tipo** `Gastos` (que no es lo mismo que la otra negrita.

Como ejemplo te pongo la variable `panelMonto`:

1. Creas el panel la primera vez que se usa la clase con `public static JPanel panelMonto = new JPanel();`
2. Agregas elementos cada vez que creas un nuevo objeto del tipo `Gasto`. Por ejemplo en esta línea le añades una etiqueta `panelMonto.add(new JLabel("Monto"));`

Este comportamiento lo repites en cada parte del código que dices que te sale repetida.

Lo que debes hacer:

1. Eliminar esas declaraciones estáticas que no sirven para nada, nada mas que para que desde cualquiera parte de tu código se puedan cambiar esos elementos (incluso declararlos `null`). Esto es una muy mala práctica de programación
2. Dejar de crear nuevas instancias cada vez que quieras mostrar una ventana. En su lugar están otras formas de deshacerse de las ventanas como por ejemplo `dispose()` o `setVisible(false)`. Después cuando quieras volver a mostrarla la vuelves a poner visible.

Si sigues el código de la pregunta que puse como duplicada harás lo que quieres.